# What is this Android Circular View

Tags: android, user-interface, android-view

I often see this UI pattern on Android. It consists of a circle .

First [Google Fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness) uses it.

[image]

[Timely](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely) has the same UI pattern. And you can interact with it , change the timer.

[image]

It is not part of Android standard View.

- What is the name of this view / UI pattern ?
- Can you give links to similar open source library ?

Comment: Explain why you want to close this question . If this is too easy just give an answer

Comment: A quick search came up with this:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1513

and this:

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1446      Note, it wasn't me that downvoted.....

Comment: One more libary for circular seekbar: https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc

Comment: How can you search for something you don't know the name ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks everyone who posted the comments.

Let's call this custom widget **Circular SeekBar**

https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar

https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar

https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc

---

Or **Circular ProgressBar**

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1513

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1446

https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

These are custom widgets, developed by application developers - it's not part of Android Framework, yet it's relatively easy to write own circular widget. See [docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

Comment: I know how to create a Custom View. I am asking if there is a name for this UI pattern

Comment: Timely is using custom circular SeekBar, fit appliaction is using custom cirular Progress bar or something like that. They are just custom widgets.

Comment: It's just circular widget. Not an UI pattern.